# code cleanup: should fields, variables and properties be declared at the top or bottom of a class?

Tags: c#, organization

Is it pretty common to declare it near the bottom in C# code?

I seen few example where its done that way.

There are tools like Resharper which help you organize your source code, does it have an option to specify where it should create regions for me?

Comment: Usually online examples. I couldn't find a similar question here so please feel free to provide links if its a duplicate.

Comment: Doesn't matter actually but it always better to have them declared @ top.

Comment: @Rahul so you're saying it does matter...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a stylistic discussion because with the majority of compilers the placement at the top or bottom (of a class file) doesn't affect the results. Historically a lot of  people do it at the top, but I like to leave them at the bottom.

Why?

Because once I've declared that member variable, I don't need to see it anymore - it shows up in my intellisense, so I don't need it in my face. When you open a file, you see the top - I want to see my code straight away, not a bunch of variable declarations. This is especially relevant because variable definitions are not a natively collapsible region in the VS editor, so if they're at the top you are forced to scroll past them. If I need to jump to it then Visual Studio's <kbd>F12</kbd> or just a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> will take me there.

This is a style that some may find hard to deal with initially, but it does grow on you quite quickly. This is a particularly good approach on files that are more mature. You will also find that if you are using a plugin like ReSharper it is smart enough to put generated declarations with all the others - which means if you have them at the bottom that's where ReSharper will put it. Of course this can get messy if you have multiple classes in a file, but if you do then variable definition placement is the least of your stylistic issues.

Edit:

at the risk of drifting off topic, a comment on using a `#region` block instead: I use regions all the time, I love them because they help me collapse code down out of the way. However using them requires discipline as it is easy for non-related code to make its way inside the region. How many times have you looked for code only to find it buried in a `#region` where it didn't belong?

Comment: I read your first line like: "Normal people do it at the...." :) time to get some sleep here zzzzzzzzz

Comment: You can keep the variables "out of your face" if you enclose them in a #region

Comment: Code organization is less important with ReSharper's CTRL+F12 (List Members), but I agree I would very much like to have ReSharper put members in regions according to rules. For instance, I prefer having "Public methods/properties/fields", "Private methods" and "Private fields/properties", or more fine grained in some cases.

Comment: I suppose my follow up question is, what order should properties and fields be at the bottom of the file? And what about properties with backing fields?

Comment: @Chucky to be honest it doesn't matter - for me it's just to get them out of the way. If we're going to be semantic I'd put the properties declarations (with our without backing fields) above the field definitions which are then above the variable declarations - so almost the reverse of what you normally see. Works for me, might seem weird to others.

Comment: What an uninformed answer I just read. The only thing that expresses the reason for your class are the member variables, and the first thing you need to see when you open the file trying to understand what the other guy did. I don't care about your mess of code because if I can see the variables I can implement the code in no time without even looking at your disaster of class.

Comment: @PabloAriel I'm trying to make sense of your comment? You don't seem to have read my answer properly and taken the time to understand it? Where the member variables go largely doesn't matter, especially to the compiler. And I don't need to see a long list of member variables to be able to fix code.

Comment: Where things go matter, especially to the programmers who have to read the code you hide. I don't need to read broken code in order to rewrite it completelly in a few minutes as long as I have access to the data, as the data is the only reason for the code to exist.

Answer (score 4):

I declare them at top. Try out [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/)... I think it will give you a recommendation on that, and a million other style issues... its kinda cool... And you can disable rules you disagree with

Comment: The link is broken, but on github StyleCop seems a dead project now. Also, this answer doesn't give a *reason* for whichever option is chosen.

Answer (score 3):

My (late) five cents on this topic:

I like **stateless** programming. Before auto-implemented properties existed, the number of private fields in a class was a rough measure of its statefulness. That's why I preferred to keep them at the top to have a quick impression. For the same reason, now I like to keep auto properties grouped together at the top.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no common convention. Some people prefer grouping the things logically: fields and the methods/properties operating with them go together. Others prefer putting public things on the top and private at the bottom.

What is really important, is that you use the style consistent with your team's style. Or, if there is no team style yet, try to convince the team to adhere to one (you'll need to persuade them that your style is better than no style).

Comment: Consistency is the most important thing.